# Is built-in checking Android/iOS permissions on runtime possible?

Tags: unity, android, ios, permission

I have a game with some levels, coded to both `Android` and `iOS`.

One of the levels late in the game uses a `Microphone`, so the app asks the user at the start (at the start of the application) to accept the `Microphone` permission.

If he does accept, everything is fine.

If he doesn't, `Microphone.Start()` method doesn't really work and I can't do anything about it.

What I should do is that in level's `start()` I should check if he has the permission and handle it, but...

I can't find a built-in way to check that on both `Android` and `iOS`.

Is there any, or I should download two different libs (for both platforms) and check it natively?

This is what I've tried:

```
    audio.clip = Microphone.Start ("Built-in Microphone", true, 999, FREQUENCY);

    Debug.Log("CLIP: " + audio.clip); // not null

    if(audio.clip == null)
    {
        GameManager.Instance().ForceComplete();
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        audio.Play ();

    }catch(Exception ex) // no exception here
    {
        GameManager.Instance().ForceComplete();
        return;
    }

    //...
```

Comment: Maybe something like this will help: https://github.com/sanukin39/UniAndroidPermission (I've also deleted my answer as none of it is of any help).

Comment: Yes, I'll probably use this one for Android and the code from their forums for iOS. I hate that. 5 mb to the APK size in order to fix one bug made by Unity.